# data is not transferred to the Angular component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I use `my-table` Angular component from the AngularJS code:

```
// AngularJS code
// src/template/expanded-table.html 

...
<div ng-show="tableLoadedSuccess" class="table-view-port">
      <my-table ng-if="tableLoadedSuccess"
                [model]="tableModel"
                [dataSource]="data">
      </my-table>
</div>
...
```

In the Controller I have:

```
// AngularJS code
// src/js/modules/ExpandedTableController.js


function ExpandedTableController(
    trailsService,
    ...
) {
...
   var searchTrails = function() {
        let settings = $scope.persistState.trails.trailsExpandedTableSettings;
        trailsService
            .getTrailEvents(settings, $scope.filterParam)
            .then(function(resp) {
                $scope.data = [1,2,3]; // just to test with this simple array
                $scope.tableLoadedSuccess = true;
            });
    };
...
    _.extend($scope, {
        ...
        tableLoadedSuccess: false,
        data: [],
        tableModel: new EventTableModel(trailsExpandedTableSettings),
        ...
    });

    ...
    searchTrails();
    ...
```

TableComponent:

```
// Angular code
// src/ts/app/shared/components/table/table.component.ts

...
export class TableComponent<T> implements OnInit {
   @Input() dataSource: T[];
   ...
   ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Table component dataSource: ' + this.dataSource);
   }
   ...
```

For some reason, I have `undefined` in `this.dataSource` in the code above.

[image]

**UPDATED:** I tried to wrap `$scope.tableLoadedSuccess = true`in `timeout` in case if the data might not be retrieved yet when hitting ngOnInit lifecycle hook:

```
// AngularJS code
// src/js/modules/ExpandedTableController.js

...
trailsService
            .getTrailEvents(settings, $scope.filterParam)
            .then(function(resp) {
                $scope.data = [1, 2, 3];
                $timeout(function () {
                    if ($scope.tableLoadedSuccess) {
                        $scope.tableLoadedSuccess = true;
                        $scope.$apply();
                    }
                }, 50000);
            });
...
```

I got `dataSource` as undefined, but TableComponent is rendered after some time (50000).

Comment: if the data is retrieved asynchronously, the data might not been retrieved yet when hitting `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook.

Comment: yes, it makes sense, thanks a lot @Gerome. Maybe you have an idea of how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution. I need to pass data to the component without camel case, but with a dash (like this `[data-source]="data"`):

```
// AngularJS code
// src/template/expanded-table.html 

...
<div ng-show="tableLoadedSuccess" class="table-view-port">
      <my-table ng-if="tableLoadedSuccess"
                [model]="tableModel"
                [data-source]="data">
      </my-table>
</div>
...
```